# Multithreading in webservices

Tags: java, multithreading, web-services

I am using webservices in my application,but i am facing the following performance(huge time tsking) problem.
Working on the travel domain application.on searching the travel services.
I am searching Flight,Hotel,Car and Forex services,

Flight service contains 3 webservices
1.galileo,Ezeego and makemy trip webservices(consumes 15 seconds to get response)

Hotel service contains 3 webservices
1.galileo,Hotelspro and Bookings.com webservices(consumes 25 seconds to get response)

Car service contains 3 webservices
1.cartrwaler webservices(consumes 15 seconds to get response)

and totally it will take 60 seconds to get the whole response from all services.

I am using JAVA programming in a sequential way i am hitting the api.
Can anyone please suggest me how can i reduce the performance time(5 sec) by using javatechnology.

I think Multithreading is the way to do ,but in multithreading which concept i have to use,please guilde me.

Comment: A very important question... what frameworks are supporting your service calls?

Comment: Though Matt's answer is correct; it may be safer, specially since you are new to multi-threading, to ensure that you support some basics on connection pooling, timeouts, retries, etc. Then ensure that you simply cannot optimize the http connection any further... Once that is done you are probably free to move to multithreading, but theres thing to consider when you do that.  It seems you still want this action to be atomic, so coordination is something you to watch, specially if you are returning all calls as a single result to the user.

Comment: Thanks for the reply back,Can you please give me an simple example in an elaborated way.

Comment: What frameworks are you using to do your rest calls? Just httpClient? using spring? Using a different tool?

Comment: i am using httpclient

Answer (score 0):

Use an `ExecutorService` to submit tasks to call each of the various web services in independent threads, and then wait for the `Future`s returned to have a result.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like the following:

Keep in mind, the ClosableHttpAsyncClient has a bunch of toys you can tune it with.
I would read up on the documentation for HttpClient and the closable one.

This will also allow you to use a pooled connection manager with the other 3 services and pass in the client to each of the services leaving them singletons. This lets you have one place to configure and fine tune all these clients and provide your data in an async way.

```
public class FlightService {
    CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpClient;

    public FlightService(CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpClient){
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public static class FlightInfo{
    private Map<String, String> airlineDataForService1;
    private Map<String, String> airlineDataForService2;
    private Map<String, String> airlineDataForService3;

    FlightInfo(HttpResponse service1, HttpResponse Service2, HttpResponse service3){
            //do stuff with data here
    }

}

    public FlightInfo getFlightInfo(){
        return new FlightInfo(callFlightService1().get(), callFlightService2().get(), callFlightService3().get());
    }

    private Future<HttpResponse> callFlightService1(){
        return callService("flightService1.com");
    }

    private Future<HttpResponse> callFlightService2(){
        return callService("flightService2.com");
    }

    private Future<HttpResponse> callFlightService3(){
        return callService("flightService3.com");
    }    

    private Future<HttpResponse> callService(String serviceUrl){
        try{
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(serviceUrl);
            httpClient.open();
            return httpClient.execute(request, null);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        //handle retries here
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
          //throw 500 here
    } finally {
        try {
        httpClient.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
        // throw 500 
            }
        }          
        return null;
  }
```